# How can I insert a vector at multiple points in an existing vector?

Tags: python, numpy

Given the vectors `a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, -1, 5, 6, -1, 7, 8, -1, 9])` and `b = np.array([999, 999, 999])`, how can I insert vector `b` into vector `a` before each index of `a` that holds the value `-1`?

To illustrate, I would like to obtain the following output:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 999, 999, 999, -1, 5, 6, 999, 999, 999, -1, 7, 8, 999, 999, 999, -1, 9])
```

I have tried using `np.insert`, but I'm clearly missing something since:

```
In [1]: np.insert(a, np.nonzero(a == -1)[0], b)
Out[1]: array([  1,   2,   3,   4, 999,  -1,   5,   6, 999,  -1,   7,   8, 999, -1,   9])
```

What gives?  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to repeat the indices you supply to `np.insert()`:

```
In [48]: np.insert(a, np.repeat(np.where(a == -1)[0], b.size), b)
Out[48]: 
array([  1,   2,   3,   4, 999, 999, 999,  -1,   5,   6, 999, 999, 999,
        -1,   7,   8, 999, 999, 999,  -1,   9])
```